# Select tag value in html disappears when selecting a value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select tag in html which has a value from angularjs. Everytime I select a value, the select tag will be empty. Why? How to fix it?

```
$scope.getAll = function(){
     $http.post()....
     $scope.places = response.data;
};

$scope.getAll();

$scope.sample = function(str){
   alert(str);
};
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="sample(val)">
     <option ng-repeat="place in places" value="place.name">{{place.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In code above, when I select some value of the select tag it alerts me the value but the select tag goes empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recommend instead of using `ng-repeat` use `ng-options`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

 $scope.places = [ {name: 'California'},
                          {name: 'New York'},
                          {name: 'Cochin'}
                        ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="val" ng-change="sample(val)" ng-options="place.name as place.name for place in places">
</select>
{{val}}
</div>
```

Comment: Vote up because it's an smart answer. Ah, Got your 4,000 points :)

Answer (score 2):

When setting the value of the option as an expression, try using `ng-value` .
While your question is confusing, I'm guessing that the alert shows up as `place.name`

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="sample(val)">
  <option ng-repeat="place in places" ng-value="place.name">{{place.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Or if you want to set the value of the select attribute itself, you can use,

```
<select ng-model="val" ng-change="sample(val)">
  <option ng-repeat="place in places" value="{{place.name}}">{{place.name}}</option>
</select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/fAbqV1wG2VuF069lt3bm?p=preview

This might be able to guide you further.